# Controlling number of channels in weight/kernel in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

To implement a specific function, I need "input_channels" number of kernels in my layer, each having only a single channel depth, and not depth = "input_channels". I need to convolve one kernel with one channel of the input, thus the output of the layer would have "input_channels" number of kernels.

Image attached for reference - 
[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

(if anyone wishes to know what all i have tried yet -
In the conv2d function of tensorflow, if I specify number of kernels = 1 to do this, then it will sum over all input_channels and number of output_channels will be 1, since it always initialises kernel depth = "input_channels".

Another option is to specify number of number of kernels = input_channels in conv2d function but this would create "input_channels" number of kernels of depth "input_channels", thus adding lot of complexity and incorrect implementation of my layer.

Yet another thing I tried was to initialise a kernel of volume (kernel_height, kernel_width, input_channels) and loop over the third dimension to convolve only a single input channel with a single kernel. But the tensorflow conv2d function requires a rank 4 kernel to work and gives the following error -

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 3 for 'generic_act_func_4/Conv2D' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,28,28], [28,28].
```

)

Comment: Dear, probably the error occurs in (kernel_height, kernel_width, input_channels), its 3 parameters (means rank 3), but the error said it should be rank for, means it needs the fourth parameters, which I think the number of the filters in this conv.